# Using jQuery to add class to containing li when a checkbox inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

### Objective

Highlight (by adding a `background-color` to) the "row" `<li>` if a (nested) checkbox inside that row is clicked.

### Background

In this feature I am working on the interface for a file management system. When a user clicks the checkbox they can then delete all the files checked. to give them visual feedback, i want all of their selected files to have a background color. This will be done by clicking a checkbox, then i want the `<li>` to be colored.

### Current state

I found various helpful answers on stackoverflow but have a gap in knowledge and trying to fill that in. Most answers use the parent element. But that only helps me by coloring that specific parent that holds the checkbox.

[image]

### Code

I have this demo on [codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/XmqxOE)

#### jQuery

```
$("#this-list :checkbox").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
});
```

#### CSS

```
.checked {
    background: red;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="this-list">

        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    song.mp3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    2011
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    1 gb
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    2 min
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    <!-- More <li>s -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You might find jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) helpful, e.g.  `closest('li')`.

Comment: You want `$(this).parents('.row').toggleClass("checked");`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could use `closest` to get the closest checkboxs `li` element:

```
$("#this-list :checkbox").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass("checked");
});
```

this method will bubble up the DOM starting from the checkbox until it finds a match for the given selector (`li` in this case).

Comment: Thank you, this answers me in the context i wrote the question, so i accepted it. In production however i had to go with `$(this).closest('.row').toggleClass("checked");
 ` to get the styling close to the spec. The lesson about the `.closest` definitely helped.

Answer (score 7):

**Use .parents([selector])**

For the li you want this

```
$(this).parents('li').toggleClass("checked");
```

Or if you only want the row highlighted

```
$(this).parents('.row').toggleClass("checked");
```

Or if you only want the cell highlighted

```
$(this).parents('.col-md-2').toggleClass("checked");
```

Comment: Great feedback. The solution for the `<li>` is in context. But the solution for the `.row` is what is is giving me the best result from a styling perspective. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are very close! You can use the .parents() method of jQuery and pass in the class .row. It would look like this:

```
$("#this-list :checkbox").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents(".row").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

EDIT:

As @showdev mentioned, if you want the li element, you can just do:

```
$(this).parents("li").toggleClass("checked");
```

Answer (score 2):

As in this [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gazQpP)

```
$("#this-list :checkbox").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("checked");
});
```

Alternatively, since the checkbox is contained inside a `div` which is inside the target `li` you can use: [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdRrpX)

```
$("#this-list :checkbox").on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("checked");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another `.parent()` to add the `checked` class to the row (the parent of the parent):

```
$(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("checked");
```

See this [CodePen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYeQbE).